# What is the green beverage that Stark makes for the Avengers?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, iron-man, avengers-age-of-ultron

In the movie *Avengers: Age of Ultron*, the Avengers return to Stark tower after Clint is wounded. Whilst Dr. Cho works on healing Clint, Tony Stark walks in with a tray of five transparent cups containing a green beverage for the group members.

**What is that green beverage?**

Comment: Knowing stark is an alcoholic,  absinthe.

Comment: Stark is famously an Los Angeles-kinda guy in the MCU, with the swagger and style of a Hollywood movie star, so I assumed it was a kale shake or something similar.  Come to think of it, wasn't he drinking a green shake of some kind in *Iron Man 2*, to help combat the arc reactor poisoning?

Comment: @Nerrolken: He was drinking a chlorophyll smoothie thing. Could be the same mix.

Comment: Knowing Tony, it could have been any one of 100 green mixed cocktails.

Comment: It wasn't the same as in *Iron Man 2*, the only reasoning is that right after they cut away when Tony tells the Asian chick that "that's the plan" (to leave the clunky metal toys in the dust), you will see the always beautiful Scarlet Johansson drinking it and of course he wouldn't make that for everyone. -just my thoughts.

Comment: @user16696 Knowing Stark is a connoisseur, he wouldn't have served them absinthe without the spoon, sugar, and a pitcher of ice water.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absinthe#Preparation

Comment: Stark seems like the type to appreciate a Pan Galactic Gargle Blaster.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

More than likely it's some variation on the classic [Superfood smoothie](http://www.odwalla.com/products/smoothies/original-superfood) While the benefits of so called "superfoods" are up for debate, their popularity among the nouveau health conscious crowd is without question. Tony is seen drinking liquid chlorophyll to combat palladium poisoning in Iron Man II, my guess is he stuck with it, adding some fillers such as kiwi and apples to make it more palatable.

Comment: Do we have a source for the kiwi though? /s

Comment: I'm really hoping you mean kiwi _fruit_ there.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like chlorophyll, which Tony mentions drinking in Iron Man 2 as a way to counteract the palladium poisoning. Wheatgrass is a bit lighter in color, and chlorella/spirulina would have some graininess. This looks very clear with just a bit of foam from being blended. There'd be no reason for him to blend it unless he added some citrus or sweetener to make it more palatable. It's a good detox, but doesn't offer much in the way of protein/energy for recovery. You can mix a tablespoon of liquid chlorophyll (available at health food stores) with 8 ounces of water, but if you want a true green superfood drink, I'd go with spirulina (which contains all essential amino acids) or a blend like Amazing Grass.

Comment: Welcome, a good answer, however can I suggest you remove the parts about recipe making and "better super foods"? As a Sci-fi and Fantasy Q&A site we prefer to keep our answers on topic and some users may be misguided by your (seemingly) correct answer because of an irrelevant detail.